# Most elegant method to calculate $\int^\pi_0 (x\sin x)^2 dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution, integration-by-parts

$\displaystyle \int^\pi_0 (x\sin x)^2 dx$.

I can easily use integration by parts to solve this integral; however, it is quite messy and I'm just wondering if there exists another alternative method that is more elementary and elegant.

I have tried the substitutions $u = \pi -x$ and $u = \pi / 2 -x$ but they do not seem to help very much.

Comment: You can simplify it a little using the identity $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$

Comment: Yes, but then integration by parts is still required and it is still quite messy.

Answer (score 5):

$$I=-\left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}\left(\int_0^{\pi}\sin x\sin a x\,dx\right)\right|_{a=1}.$$

Comment: Feynman comes to the rescue.  +1

Comment: Although it should be said, once we find the second derivative of this integral we find it has singularities at $a = 1$; and the limit is not straight forward to evaluate.

Comment: @SimonS This is because $\sin x$ is a "bad" function - the "good" one would be the exponential. The suggestion is that to avoid integration by parts in $\int_b^c x^2 e^{x} dx$ one should consider instead $$ \int_c^d e^{(a+1)x} dx = \frac{ e^{(a+1)d} - e^{(a+1)c}}{ a+1} $$ and expand in powers of $a$.

Comment: @Startwearingpurple Good point. All in all though, this approach is now clearly more difficult conceptually and computationally than the 'high school calculus' answer.

Answer (score 5):

Using the identity $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\int^\pi_0 x^2\sin^2 x\; dx &= \frac{1}{2}\int^\pi_0 x^2(1-\cos(2x)) dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int^\pi_0x^2\;dx - \frac{1}{2}\int^\pi_0x^2\cos(2x)\;dx \\
&= \frac{\pi^3}{6} -\frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{1}{2}x^2\sin(2x)\right]_0^\pi + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi x\sin(2x)\;dx \\
&= \frac{\pi^3}{6} + \frac{1}{2}\left[-\frac{1}{2}x\cos(2x)\right]_0^\pi + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi\sin(2x)\;dx \\
&= \frac{\pi^3}{6} - \frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align*}